# Diagnosing Worklight 6 SQL Adapter issue, JPA tracing

Tags: worklight-adapters

Worklight Studio 6, SQL adapter attempting connection to DB2 database.

Standard pattern for procedure

```
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : listUnassignedWorkOrders, 
    parameters : []
});
```

When I invoke my procedure I see this error

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0035E: Invocation of procedure 'SqlStatement' failed.
>   [project Infrabel01] Type 'Function' currently does not support
>   marshalling to JSON.

And the logs show

> [err] 0  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1]
>   openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a
>   ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root
>   URL
>   [file:/C:/djna-nobackup/Workspaces/WL6.0/01/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar].
>   The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log
>   level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.

How to diagnose? How would I set the trace level in worklight?

JPA docs say:

> property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO,
>   Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"

But where to put that in worklight?

Comment: The actual error was caused by a typo in the implementation, the error message is actually quite clear. The question of how one might enable JPA tracing does remain, but is now academic.

Comment: Please always add the "worklight" tag as well, otherwise we may miss the question. Pleas also write this as an Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `WorklightPU WARN` in the log is not relevant and has been removed in newer releases of Worklight.

For your actual issue, see the following developerWorks threads with the same issue that was resolved.

> Type 'Function' currently does not support marshalling to JSON.

- [developerWorks thread #1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014933895#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014933915)
- [developerWorks thread #2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014882444#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014917196)

Comment: Can you please suggest what was the workaround the links you have give is expired